# Collect garbage manually?

Tags: c#, manual, garbage

```
Person p = new Person("Bob", 10);
p = new Person("James", 20);
```

Turns out I am loosing a reference to an instance containing "Bob". If I don't want to rely on c#'s GC, how can I personally delete this instance before re-assigning p to point towards James? Just to avoid extra garbage.

Comment: Don't code like this and dispose of objects before losing reference.

Comment: There is special "DEL" button on most keyboards - just delete that extra creation from the source code :)...

Comment: If you don't want to rely on the GC the only option  is to choose something other than C#.  Though this question harks more to a misunderstanding of object life cycles or incorrect expectations.

Comment: "Before reassigning", `p` contains a reference to an object... do you want `p` to reference an non-object? If you want "undefined behavior" and program crashes, you should try with C/C++.

Comment: I performed some actions on Bob, then I need to dispose of it and perform something on jams. Clearly, its is a very simplified example, and I can't "delete" those 2 lines, since they are necessary. @AlexeiLevenkov.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes, that's exactly what I am trying to figure out at the moment, how to dispose of them? I do contain a reference to the old object, can I delete this instance before switching p to point at other object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reuse the instance, instead of replacing it:

```
Person p = new Person("Bob", 10);

p.Name = "James";
p.Number = 20;
```

That way there is no Bob instance that you loose Reference to.

However, for code readability and to avoid potential bugs you should not reuse variables in that way.

Comment: That's something I didn't think of. Re-using should work, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You can only ask GC to perform collection, but there is no way to say it will actually take your object (neither you can ask GC to collect just one object).

> [`GC.Collect` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> Forces an immediate garbage collection of all generations.

And you shouldn't do that unless you have **very good** reason (looks like you don't).

Comment: That's very strange :/ I do have a refence to a heap memory address.   I should be able to clear it before re-directing the pointer p towards another instance.

Comment: No, you don't have a reference to memory address. You have a reference to an object. It's not exactly the same think as pointer in C/C++ (but that's a topic for much longer discussion). You should not even bother thinking about that. That's the beauty of Garbage Collection. That's how .NET Framework works. If you need/want to do stuff like that , use C++ or C.

Comment: +1. @NoobCoder - I think you want to write your code in C++, not C# - you'll get all benefits and drawbacks of manual memory management this way in much more accommodating environment. GC run-times are generally don't have a way to do manual cleanup, especially for single object (.Net, Java, JavaScript.... )

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to force garbage collection by calling Collect, but most of the time, this should be avoided because it may create performance issues.

Taken from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx